# stop mask error remains after deleting offending text in eagle

Tags: eaglecad, error, drc

I ran the DRC for dirty pcbs, and it's giving me these stop mask errors for values assigned.

In this particular example, It's D1 with a 4148 label. In the first image, you can see the 4148 value that is causing the stop mask error with the 5v pad. I remove the '4148' value for D1, and you can see that for some reason the '4' and part of the '1' from '4148' still remains.

How do I get the remaining 41 removed from the pad to get rid of the error? I tried to remove the diode and the 5v pad from the schematic, but when it's added back, the 41 remains.

Before:
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]

Comment: Did you run the DRC again?

Comment: Yes and same issue persists.

Comment: The 4 and 1 isn't there, that is the outline of the error. Try typing "DRC" in the command line and run it that way.

Comment: Not an Eagle user but it looks like your outline silk screen is over both pads.

Answer (score 1):

You are addressing the wrong problem.

The real problem is that this diode package is crap.  This kind of problem is one reason it's usually better to make your own packages than to use things you find lying around in some dark corner of the web.

None of the package outline should be over the pads in the first place.  Most board houses will automatically clip the silkscreen to the soldermask, but you shouldn't rely on that.  In this particular case, it will be difficult to see the diode polarity once the cathode bar is clipped to the soldermask.  There may be little or nothing left, depending on registration, and how conservative the board house got with tolerances.

The "4148" is likely not a problem at all.  In a competently designed package (OK, that may be a stretch here), that would be text in the tValues layer resulting from the VALUE variable.

You assume up front that values and labels text will overlap things or be in inconvenient places anyway.  Ignore this during part placement and routing.  Once that is done, you smash all the parts and clean up the text placements.  So the real answer is that "4148" should simply be moved to someplace it doesn't cause trouble.

In a dense layout where there is no place nearby, just "delete" it from the silkscreen.  You can't actually delete the text, but you can move it to a layer that doesn't contribute to the silkscreen, or anything else.  I always create layer 101 and call it "trash" for this purpose.

Find whoever made this mess of a package, and run away.  Delete anything else you got from the same source, as none of it can be trusted now.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I didn't create this design. I grabbed it and wanted to modify it a bit, but it's full of errors....

Answer (score 0):

seems that restarting eagle removes the remnants of the old value.  Not ideal, but it works.

v8.3.1 on MacOS.